# Extract number(amount of money) from a sentence in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsregularexpression

I need to extract out the amount from the sentences containing amount information like "Rs 500".

E.g => "Product costs Rs 500, would you like to buy???",

I need the solution in regex, please share the code using NSRegularExpression class to extract amount from the sentence, "Rs" must be case-insensitive.

I am weak in writing regex, hence need the same.

Comment: If you're weak in writing regex, maybe start by [learning regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info) rather than asking folks to provide the code? It's not *that* complicated.

Comment: fantastic tutorial: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: SO is not a site for requesting people to write your code for you. It is a site where you can get help with a programming issue you are having. Post details about what you have tried and what you need help with.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not efficient in using Regular Expression. You can use NSScanner to get the number as below

```
// Input
NSString *originalString = @"Product costs Rs 500, would you like to buy???";

// Intermediate
NSString *numberString;

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:originalString];
NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];

// Throw away characters before the first number.
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:NULL];

// Collect numbers.
[scanner scanCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:&numberString];

// Result.
int number = [numberString integerValue];
```

Hope it Helps you...